# How to make one code run only after the other is done in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, synchronization

I am new to async and sync mechanism.
In my code I have to perform one code line only after the other is done.
It looks something like this:

```
    func something(){

    let workerQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
            workerQueue.async{
         let info = getInfoFromTheWeb()//I need the info value in order to perform the next line
         saveToDB(info: info)

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
       //update a label text in the ui after getting and saving that info
      }

    }
}
```

Your professional thoughts please..

Comment: Just go through the concepts of GCD and how it works [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1). You will find the answer yourself for sure :)

Comment: lines are executed one after the other, what is the issue? Is `getInfoFromTheWeb` async? Does not look like it, you are already on a separate thread where you can perform synchronous requests. That means when `saveToDB` is reached the web info is already present.

Comment: I think your concept/issue is related to the use of completion handler  [here](https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/) is a great tutorial for it!

Comment: You need to use dispatch_sync, not dispatch_async.

Synchronous and Asynchronous Execution
Each work item can be executed either synchronously or asynchronously. When a work item is executed synchronously with the sync method, the program waits until execution finishes before the method call returns. When a work item is executed asynchronously with the async method, the method call returns immediately.


https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch

Comment: @MH175 In this case I need the info to have value in it. What you suggest won't do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your should `DispatchGroup`. By using `DispatchGroup` one function/line of code will wait until the other function completes execution.

For example

```
let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
   myGroup.enter()
   let info = getInfoFromTheWeb()
```

When you get `info` from simple call

```
myGroup.leave()
```

When your call `leave()` function following code will be execute

```
myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {

            saveToDB(info: info)
           /// Update UI elements
        }
```

Comment: Usman, is the default in iOS is to run the code in asynchronous matter? @Usman Javed

Comment: yes and for more detail I suggest you to read DispatchGroup in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
func something() {

    let workerQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
    workerQueue.async{

        if let info = getInfoFromTheWeb() {
            saveToDB(info: info)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //update a label text in the ui after getting and saving that info
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Bobby. And what if not? info = getInfoFromTheWeb(). Then saveToDB() won't be performed at all?

Comment: That is correct, you can have an Else statement if you need to perform some task if info is nil.